# Java socket, using custom toString method with the same message

Tags: java

I have a simple anon inner socket class like below:

```
  Socket anonSocket = new Socket(){

        @Override
        public void close(){

        }
        @Override
        public String toString(){

            return"uncloseable";
        }
    };
```

My issue is that the i want the toString() method to return "uncloseable" as it already do. But also have the default socket message. For example running this code without my custom toString() method printing the anonSocket would result in the text
"Socket[unconnected]" i want to get this text + "uncloseable" in my toString() method. How can I achieve this?

Comment: With `super.toString()`.

Comment: `super.toString()`. But really, subclassing Socket and preventing it to close seems like a horrible idea to me.

Comment: it's for learning, it's not something i would use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When overriding a superclass method you have two options, to completely remove the logic of the superclass by implement a standalone method that doesn’t depend on the superclass method, like you have done now, or you can extend the functionality of the superclass method by including a call to it in the new method together with your own logic.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return super.toString() + " uncloseable"
}
```